# Binding custom directive on Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I have a custom directive on my html page. For my component msgfooter I have different errorType messages:

```
<msgfooter [errorType]="Invalid server"> <msgfooter>
```

or

```
<msgfooter [errorType]="Few Parameters"> <msgfooter>
```

I usually create a string on my .ts file. But in custom directives I cannot do this:

```
<msgfooter [errorType]={{myCustomMessage}}> <msgfooter>
```

Error:

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In Angular 2 you are able to do 3 kinds of inputs:

```
<msgfooter [errorType]="myCustomMessage"><msgfooter>
```

or

```
<msgfooter errorType="Invalid server"><msgfooter>
```

or

```
<msgfooter errorType="{{myCustomMessage}}">
```

The first one will be evaluated so it'll look for a specific variable (`myCustomMessage`) in your component.

The second one will just pass a string.

This third one will evaluate the variable `myCustomMessage`, stringify it and pass it to the `errorType` input.

---

You can only use `[]` **or** `{{}}` but not both at the same time.

Comment: Actually, the third one is taken as a string still and it doesn't evaluate the variable. You are basically just passing a `{{myCustomMessage}}` string value.

The third input would be `bind-errorType="myCustomMessage"`.

Comment: @EdMorales Not really. Angular 2 will evaluate `{{ }}` when passed to attribute. Try to play with it.

Comment: What version of angular are you using? Im using rc.0 and doesnt work.

Comment: Just saw, beta.17. TBH it mightve changed, cause in rc.0 its taken as a string. but who knows. Many things will change until its mature enough.

Comment: Plunker is in beta.17 but I checked also locally (rc.1) to make sure I haven't missed anything. Works the same for both.